# Title VII of 1991

Tags: civil-law

what is the protection requirement of Title VII of 1991 the plaintiff must follow to successfully file an action? 
I already included the time limit .

Comment: Are you asking what the procedure is for filing a lawsuit in federal court? Or is this about filing an official complaint? Or about contacting an EEO counselor?

Comment: what are the requirements the plaintiff must follow to file

Comment: File what? A lawsuit?

Comment: yes a civil action

Answer (score 1):

The EEOC rules are summarized [here](https://www.eeoc.gov/employees/lawsuit.cfm). Briefly, there are prerequisites, such as filing a charge of discrimination, and when they dismiss your charge, you will get a Notice-of-Right-to-Sue. You then have to file the suit within 90 days (I assume that is the time limit you referred to). Then you either hire an attorney to pursue the lawsuit for you, or you do it yourself. If you are suing under the Equal Pay Act, you may go directly to court. Having decided who to sue and what the cause of action is, and having checked statutes of limitation, you draft a formal complaint setting out the elements, fill out some forms, and file it with the clerk of the relevant court.

The rules of federal procedure (general) are [here](http://%20ht%20tp://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/), so follow them (to the extent relevant). Some of them are more informational / definitional, e.g. Rule 3 "A civil action is commenced by filing a complaint with the court". You also need to observe district-specific rules. If you were in Western Washington, you could use [this handy *pro se* guide](http://www.wawd.uscourts.gov/sites/wawd/files/ProSeManual4_8_2013wforms.pdf).